# Prediction in Python with SKLearn not working

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to predict the future values of a share with SKLearn regressors (but it could be the next value of anything, I've tried the same function on Covid Cases data with the same results) but it doesn't work.

I've written a function that takes my train dataset, the target variable, the test Xs and the features to take into account and gives back the prediction:

```py
def predict_share_valuesGRDBST(data, target_variable, X_test, features=None):
    # Split data into features (X) and target (y)
    if features:
        X = data[features]
    else:
        X = data.drop(target_variable, axis=1)
    y = data[target_variable]
        
    # Fit Gradient Boosting model to training data
    model = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=200,random_state=20)
    model.fit(X, y)
    # Use model to make predictions on next num_predictions values
    next_values = model.predict(X_test[features])
    return next_values
```

- variable data is like

| Date | CloseValue | OpenValue | TradeVolume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-01-19 | 100 | 90 | 1000 |
| 2023-01-20 | 110 | 101 | 1100 |

- Target_variable is 'CloseValue'
- X_test is like data but with values in future dates
- features variable is like ['OpenValue', 'TradeVolume', 'Date']

but the returned values don't fit at all:
[image: Values Groundboost]

I've tried with other regressors (AdaBoost, RandomForest) but they al give me the same, wrong, results:
[image: Values all regressors]

that's why I'm think that I am doing something wrong and it's not just a problem of correlation between variables, it seems that they're working on wrong data but I cannot figure out how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: can u paste your plot code

Comment: I'd be surprised if the model performs well, but it might also be interesting to see the predictions of each model for the entire time period.